# How to load a image form local address in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to load an image from the computer and output txt file of each pixel in the hex of rgb24.

The problem is I cannot load image from a local address, I used CHROME.

here is the code:

```
function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    return "0x00" + ((1 << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b).toString(16).slice(1);
}
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
//var imgUrl = 'file:///C:/Users/thiennguyen/Pictures/Untitled.png';
var img = new Image();img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
img.src = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1582803824594-65b5b4632cad?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=512&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=512';
img.onload = function() {
c.width = img.width;
c.height = img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,c.width, c.height);
    var arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
        var j = 0;
        var r, g, b, a;
        imgData.data[i + 0] = imgData.data[i + 0];
        r = imgData.data[i + 0];
        imgData.data[i + 1] = imgData.data[i + 1];
        g = imgData.data[i + 1];
        imgData.data[i + 2] = imgData.data[i + 2];
        b = imgData.data[i + 2];
        imgData.data[i + 3] = imgData.data[i + 3];
        a = imgData.data[i + 3];
        imgData.data[i + 3] = imgData.data[i + 3];
        arr.push(rgbToHex(r, g, b));
    }
console.log(arr)

var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');

hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(arr.join('\n'));
hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
hiddenElement.download = 'myFile.txt';
hiddenElement.click();

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zw2509ct/2/

Comment: You need to use the `<input type="file">` to allow the user to select the image, and then handle the file that was selected. You can't access the image directly

Comment: You can use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to read data from user's computer. You can learn [how to use it on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example_Showing_thumbnails_of_user-selected_images).